# Best approach for enlarging washer and dryer compartment

Tags: remodeling, laundry

I have a laundry room that has a section reserved for the washer and dryer with a drain.  Presumably it exists in case either unit leaks for some reason.  The problem is, I ordered a new washer and dryer and the depth of the units is 33 1/2".  However, the space in this section is only 32" deep before you get to either the backwall or the front lip.  The material of the lip is similar to non-tile surfaces you see in some showers.  Possibly a hard plastic with a shiny surface.

[image]

Ideally I would like to remove the entire front lip as it's really going to get in the way.  However, I'm not sure how much of a risk there is that it could somehow flood out of the room.

So my questions are:

- What risks are there with removing the front lip?
- What sort of professional could help with this work? (I wouldn't even know who to call)
- Are there other strategies that could work that allows me to fit my washer and dryer in this space?

Comment: You could possibly raise them up on something higher than the lip of the enclosure, if the height is not inconvenient. Ideally the front part of that raised platform would be waterproofed and slope to drain back into the pan. Looks like and may actually be a shower base, suggesting "what sort  of contractors" if you want to change it.

Comment: Also, if this is designed to be a shower, the power point might be limited. Try running a heater or electric kettle for some minutes first to see if it works. Or check electric safety switches.